# responsive issue at display

Tags: html, css, email

I have created a responsive mail that the client receives when buying a ticket. In the same file I have two different CSS classes:

```
*[class=noDisplayAtMobile] { display: none !important; display:none; mso-hide:all }

*[class=displayAtMobile] { display: block !important; width:100% !important; max-width:650px !important ; max-height:inherit!important; float:none !important; overflow:visible !important; }
```

The first class is used to display the mail on the desktop and the second displays it for mobile devices,when i use the second class at the original (fullscreen) layout i use the follow style to not display at fullscreen

```
   style="width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;"
```

I see the responsive output when my browser window is less than 650px and the non-responsive output when it is fullscreen, but at the mail (GMail) I see both of them...

Does anyone have any ideas about what the problem is and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I assume your CSS is inline and not in a separate stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

You should try code as below

```
.your_class { display: none !important; display:none; mso-hide:all }

@media (max-width: 650px) { //apply css when screen width <=650px
.your_class { display: block !important; width:100% !important; max-width:650px !important ; max-height:inherit!important; float:none !important; overflow:visible !important; }
}
```